# TextView not working properly

Tags: android

I have a `TextView` with very long text. In Graphical layout it shows fine wrapped text but when i run this it does not wrap text.Here is my design code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:background="#ffffff" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_title"
        style="@style/dialog_header" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_title"
            style="@style/dialog_header_image"
            android:contentDescription="@string/update_reply"
            android:src="@drawable/compose" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_title"
            style="@style/dialog_header_title"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image_title" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/layout_message"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/layout_title"
        android:fadingEdge="none"
        android:fillViewport="true" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:padding="10dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_message"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:minHeight="130dp"
                android:text="Don&apos;t work too hard to give yourself the best of everything, instead make a greater effort to give God the best of yourself." />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/button_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/layout_message" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_reply"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/reply" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_forward"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/forward" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

i want to show this but it show only one line

Comment: what kind of text it shows in your textview ?

Comment: it shows only this much text `"Don't work too hard to give yourself"`

Comment: remove android:minHeight="130dp"

Comment: i tried that also, in fact i tried every possible way, but same problem

Comment: screenshot of what you think the problem is would probably help in this scenario

Answer (score 0):

Remove this

```
android:minHeight="130dp"
```

And change height value for textview

```
android:layout_height="XXXdp"
```

Comment: Try setting height to your scrollview

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
android:text="Don&apos;t work too hard to give yourself the\n best of everything, instead     make a greater\n effort to give God the best of yourself."
```

Comment: I don't want to add `\n` I want the same text as it is , because that text will be anything, so it won't work

Answer (score 0):

To get text wraping, set `android:singleLine=false` in `TextView`.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:singleLine